# I want my python program to capture output and send to a remote pc

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am fairly new to python so forgive my bad errors or stupid questions.
I made a program that can send commands from a remote computer to another computer, everything seems to work but I can't figure out how to capture the output from the client and send to the remote computer. Any help would be appreciated.
My code for the remote side :

```
import time
import sys
import socket
import os
def func():
    command = input(str("cmd or pwsh? : "))
    conn.send(command.encode())
    print("command has been sent, waiting")

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
print(host)
port = 8080
s.bind((host,port))
print("Waiting")
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Connected")

func()
x = 1
while True:
    func()
```

Code for the client side :

```
import time
import sys
import socket
import os

def input():
    command = s.recv(1024)
    command = command.decode()
    os.system(command)

s = socket.socket()
host = "192.168.100.3"
port = 8080
s.connect((host, port))
print("Connected to server ")

def input():
    command = s.recv(1024)
    command = command.decode()
    os.system(command)

input()
x = 1
while True:
    input()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

Comment: `os.system` can't get output - you have to use fucntions from module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Could you give me a sample example I can't understand how to capture an output and send back to the remote side